# minify JQuery code with $(this)

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(this).parent().find(".age").removeClass('active').children("input").prop('checked', false);
$(this).addClass('active').children('input').prop('checked', true);
```

This works, but i want to minify it and do something like this :

```
$(this).parent().find(".age").removeClass('active').children("input").prop('checked', false).find(this).addClass('active').children('input').prop('checked', true);
```

or alternatively

```
$(this).parent().find(".age").removeClass('active').children("input").prop('checked', false).children(this).addClass('active').children('input').prop('checked', true);
```

These two examples don't work, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: might be better if we can see some html codes...

Comment: Note that several of the answers involve adding calls to `.end()`. These are longer than `$(this)` that you're trying to replace, so it's not really "minifying".

Comment: i wouldnt recommend these constructs...these are called train wrecks and every time something is modified it will break

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to perform all these operations in a single chain, you can use [end()](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to get back to the previous set of matched elements:

```
$(this).parent().find(".age").removeClass("active")
                             .children("input").prop("checked", false).end()
                             .end()
                .end()
       .addClass("active").children("input").prop("checked", true);
```

The other way around is a little clearer:

```
$(this).addClass("active").children("input").prop("checked", true).end()
       .parent().find(".age").removeClass("active")
                             .children("input").prop("checked", false);
```

That said, these expressions are quite complex, and insisting on chaining them may result in less readable and maintainable code. Your mileage may vary, but chaining, like all good things, should not be abused.

Comment: @user, the order of the operations may be significant, it's hard to tell without seeing your markup. In that case, the second code snippet may fail because it shuffles things around.

Answer (score 1):

Why not cache `$(this)` to a variable instead:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.parent().find(".age").removeClass('active')
.children("input").prop('checked', false);
$this.addClass('active').children('input').prop('checked', true);
```